# How do you register a listener in service fabric (azure)

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am writing a reliable actor in service fabric who's job it will be to listen to changes in a [Firebase DB](https://www.firebase.com/features.html) and run logic based on those changes.  I have it functioning, but not correctly.  What I've done so far is write the actor code with a method called MonitorRules() which is what is listening to Firebase using a C# Firebase client wrapper called [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp).  MonitorRules() looks like this:

```
public async Task MonitorRules()
{
    FireSharp.FirebaseClient client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(new FireSharp.Config.FirebaseConfig
    {
        AuthSecret = "My5up3rS3cr3tAu7h53cr37",
        BasePath = "https://myapp.firebaseio.com/"
    });

    await client.OnAsync("businessRules",
        added: (sender, args) =>
        {
            ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage(this, $"{args.Data} added at {args.Path}");
        },
        changed: (sender, args) =>
        {
            ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage(this, $"{args.OldData} changed to {args.Data} at {args.Path}");
        }
    );            
}
```

I then call MonitorRules() after the service is registered like so in the service's Main() method:

```
fabricRuntime.RegisterActor<RuleMonitor>();
var serviceUri = new Uri("fabric:/MyApp.RuleEngine/RuleMonitorActorService");
var actorId = ActorId.NewId();
var ruleMonitor = ActorProxy.Create<IRuleMonitor>(actorId, serviceUri);

ruleMonitor.MonitorRules();
```

This "works" in that the service opens a connection to Firebase and responds to data changes.  The problem is that since the service is run on three nodes of a five node cluster, it's actually listening three times and processes each message three times.  Also, if there is no activity for a while, the service is deactivated and no longer responds to changes in Firebase.  All in all, not the right way to set something like this up I'm sure, but I can not find any documentation on how to set up a polling client like this in service fabric.  Is there a way to set this up that will adhere to the spirit of azure service fabric?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, there are a few things to familiarize yourself with here. The first is the [Actor lifecycle and garbage collection](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle/). Tl;dr: Actors are deactivated if they do not receive a client request (via ActorProxy) or a reminder for some period of time, which is configurable.

Second, Actors have [Timers and Reminders](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders/) that you can use to do periodic work, like polling a database for changes. The difference between a timer and reminder is that a timer doesn't count as "being used" meaning that the actor can still be deactivated which shuts down the timer, but a reminder counts as "being used" and can also re-activate a deactivated actor. The way to think about timers and reminders is that you're doing the polling, rather than waiting for a callback from something else like you have here with FireSharp.

Finally, calling MonitorRules from Main() is not the best idea. The reason is that Main() is actually the entry point for your actor service *host process,* which is just an EXE that is used to host instances of your actors. The *only* thing that should happen in Main() is registering your actor type and nothing else. Let's look at what's happening here in more detail:

So you deploy your actor service to a cluster. The first thing that happens is we start the host process on as many nodes as necessary to run the actor service (in your case that's 3). We enter Main() where the actor service type gets registered and at this point, that's all we *should* do, because once the actor service is registered with the host process, we'll then create an instance (or multiple instances or replicas if it's stateful) of the service, and then the service can start doing its work. For actors, that means the actor service is ready to start activating actors when a client application makes a call using ActorProxy. But with the ActorProxy call you have in Main(), you're basically saying "activate an actor on every node where this host is *when the host starts*" which is why you're listening three times.

With all that in mind, the first question to ask yourself is whether actors are the right model for you. If you just want a simple place to monitor Firebase with a FireSharp client, it might be easier just use a [reliable service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start/) instead because you can put your monitoring in RunAsync, which is started automatically when the service starts, unlike actors which need a client to activate them.

Comment: Excellent clarification on all fronts.  I can't tell you how helpful this was.